# Gradle sync failed on first startup in Android studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

It seem I'm struggled of this issue since last week because I couldn't find the same problem that I have on the internet...

My AMD Computer ran on windows xp first and trying to install the android studio 2.2.2 but I've got the problem says Incompatible Operating System so I decided to upgrade to windows 7 but I've got the same thing so I fully upgraded my computer to windows 10 pro 64 bit. Yes the issue has gone but sad to say that I've got a new problem.. Gradle stuck in

> Gradle: Resolve dependencies 'app:_debugAndroidTestCompile'

. I've waited half an hour but nothing happen.

[image]

I've done checking some possible solution like gradle version and android studio plugin version but noting happen too.

so anybody knows whats going on in this version because in few months ago I am using older version of android studio but I don't get any problem like this...

**Update:**

Is this a normal duration of gradle synchronizing? 
[image]

Comment: Run `gradle build --info` or `gradlew build --info` from command line in the project path and see, where it stops.

Comment: no is't stop but is on stuck at Gradle: Resolve dependencies 'app:_debugAndroidTestCompile' so no error wrote on console.. by the way how can I run the gradle build --info from command line?

Comment: Android Studio builds your project using default build system: Gradle. It is possible to invoke exactly the same process from command line. If compilation stops in Android Studio, then it will stop in command line too.

Comment: look at this image https://s16.postimg.org/e9ajy3105/Capture.png is that a normal duration?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried updating the gradle version? How many dependencies do you have on your project? Maybe too much dependencies can cause slow actions.

Comment: gradle version 3.2.

Comment: oh I've check again the version from project struction and its version 2.14.1 not the same as what gradle version downloaded from this site. https://gradle.org/gradle-download/

Comment: I've ran my android studio for the first time after the installation so I thought dependencias are not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting your gradle caches?  I've found sometimes these get messed-up and deleting them seems to solve the problem.

Gradle cache locates at

On Windows: %USER_HOME%.gradle/caches
On Mac/Unix: $HOME/.gradle/caches/

Comment: I confused for now because the location of gradle is in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle` and you've said the location is in Windows: %USER_HOME%.gradle/caches

Comment: The location of gradle itself, and the location of the caches is not necessarily the same. If in doubt do a search for '.gradle\caches' on your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. When I updated to 2.2.2 gradle sync begun to fail an run for 10+ mins. After a long digging through log files and gooogle search I found out it was caused by Comodo firewall blocking JCenter. After uninstalation of that traitor everything runs as before.